# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: magento

Trace:

```
#0 /home/catering/public_html/shop/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/catering/public_html/shop/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/catering/public_html/shop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/catering/public_html/shop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sh...', Array)
#4 /home/catering/public_html/shop/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `sh...', Array)
#5 /home/catering/public_html/shop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(574): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `sh...', Array)
#6 /home/catering/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(453): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->insert('shop_log_visito...', Array)
#7 /home/catering/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(318): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor))
#8 /home/catering/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php(167): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#9 /home/catering/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_Log_Model_Visitor->initByRequest(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /home/catering/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Log_Model_Visitor), 'initByRequest', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /home/catering/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#12 /home/catering/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(528): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#13 /home/catering/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php(64): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#14 /home/catering/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(408): Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action->preDispatch()
#15 /home/catering/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#16 /home/catering/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#17 /home/catering/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 /home/catering/public_html/shop/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /home/catering/public_html/shop/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

Comment: this is either a query locking issue or syntax issue. login to your mySql and check "show processlist"

Answer (score 0):

Increase the *innodb_lock_wait_timeout* in MySQL.Before that see what is current value set for it.